# opendaylight Chlorine ovsdb curl 404

Tags: opendaylight

Steps:

1. feature:install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl-ui
2. 

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/
```

or

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/
```

step2 curl return '404 not found'

curl results should be

```
{
  "topology": [
    {
      "topology-id": "ovsdb:1"
    }
  ]
}
```

reference: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/ovsdb-user-guide.html#ovsdb-southbound-plugin

Answer (score 1):

The Chlorine release of opendaylight has removed support for the old version of RESTCONF based on draft-bierman-netconf-restconf-02. See this reference for more details:

[Old RESTCONF northbound scheduled for removal](https://lists.opendaylight.org/g/dev/topic/old_restconf_northbound/87424267?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate/sticky,,,20,2,0,87424267,previd%3D1659074764984299769,nextid%3D1644352602295728126&previd=1659074764984299769&nextid=1644352602295728126)

To use the newer RFC-8040 RESTCONF version, some changes to the URL are necessary. See this link for more details:

https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/netconf/en/latest/user-guide.html

After some experimentation, I was able to get the following URL to work:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8181/rests/data/network-topology:network-topology/topology=ovsdb:1?content=config

{"network-topology:topology":[{"topology-id":"ovsdb:1"}]}
```